# Infinite exponential sum in thermodynamics

Tags: sequences-and-series

While trying to find the grand canonical partition sum for the Bose-Hubbard-Model in MFA I came across a sum of the following form:
\begin{align}
\sum_{q=0}^\infty a^{q(q-1)}b^q,\quad 0<a,b<1
\end{align}
I have been looking for hours for ways to solve this and -- while I'm sure, that this is solvable -- did not find any solution.

Thank you for your help

Comment: probably can be only approximated for $a,b\sim 1$ or $|a|<<1$ or $|b|<<1$

Comment: @user619894 that would be a shame, because $a,b$ depend on temperature and a physical simulation, which could yield any values

Comment: Have a look at [Jacobi theta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).

Comment: @WillOrrick I could bring this to the form $\sum_{q=0}^\infty a^{q^2} (b/a)^q$ and compare with $\vartheta_{00}$, but this is not equivalent to the form on wikipedia as their sum starts at $-\infty$. Thank you for the idea!